# How to intercept hardware Bar Back Button Clicked in Android in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#-4.0, xamarin.forms

I want to intercept hardware back buttion in my Xamarin Forms Portable app, At First I have login page,You have to login and it will navigate to my Homepage2.. after going to my homepage2, when i click on my hardware backbutton...It goes to my login page or the pages i opened previously.. I want to Prevent it. Can anyone please resolve me this issue..
here is my login page

```
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public async void LoginBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (UserName.Text == null || password1.Text == null)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Alert ! ", "Please Enter UserName Or/Password!", "OK");
        }
        else
        {
            string uname = UserName.Text;
            string pswd = password1.Text;
            LoginService objservice = new LoginService();
            LoginTokenModel result = await objservice.GetLogin(uname, pswd);
            LoginTokenModel logintokenmodel = new LoginTokenModel();
            logintokenmodel.User_Id = result.User_Id;
            var Login_Token = result.Login_Token;
            int user_Id = result.User_Id;

            if (uname == result.User_Nmae)
            {
               // HomePage2 HOMEPge = new HomePage2();
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new HomePage2(user_Id));
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayAlert("Alert ! ", "Invalid Credentials!", "OK");
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the App's MainPage with your Homepage2.
as you are not coming back on Login page you don'n want it in the NavigationStack.

This is what I do on successful Login:

```
if (uname == result.User_Nmae)
{
   App.Current.MainPage = new HomePage2(user_Id);
}
```

In addition you can also keep this `user_Id` stored for the second time when the user enters again in application properties and check if the user_Id exists or not, if it does just navigate to Homepage2

```
Application.Current.Properties["id"] = user_Id;
```

in App.cs onStart

```
if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("id"))
{
    var user_Id = Application.Current.Properties["id"] as string;
    MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Views.Homepage2(user_Id ));
}
else
{
  MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Views.Login());
}
```